# Compiler Design : Is "variable not declared" a syntactic error or semantic error?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, semantics, syntactic-sugar, typechecking

Is such type of an error produced during type checking or when input is being parsed?
Under what type should the error be addressed?

Comment: It depends on the language I think. For a statically-typed language (e.g. C, Scala), I would consider it a Syntax/"Syntactic" Error and expect it to happen during compilation; in a language with dynamic variable bindings (e.g. JavaScript, Ruby), I would consider it a Semantic error and expect it to happen during runtime. In any case, I voted "Not Constructive".

Comment: So in statically typed language, type checking is done during parsing?

Comment: Parsing and Type-Checking really should be considered two *different* phases of the entire Compilation process. However, this will depend upon implementation; it is imaginable - ick! - that scoping rules are enforced during the parsing. Type-Checking is more than just "scope checking": not only must the binding be defined (perhaps even assigned a value), but the types must be compatible.

Comment: Oops, clarification on my first comment: I would classify "variable not declared" as Syntax, while I could say "incompatible type" is Semantic in a static environment.

Comment: So far I've learnt that syntax analysis cannot check for declarations.  So if this error is caught by semantic analysis why is it a syntax error? Also, isn't the separation between syntax and semantic analysis just logical?

Comment: Good retort - I have no solid justification other than it is how it fits *my* classification. (Errors that occur due to invalid grammar are clearly Syntax errors, but I do not feel comfortable making a stronger assertion for errors generated by code that conforms to the grammar, even if logically unsound and catchable early on.)

Comment: Why do you think syntax analysis cannot check for declarations? A context free grammar cannot do the check, but syntax analysis is more than just a CFG. I would definitely called an undeclared variable a syntax error _in languages which requrie variables to be declared_.

Comment: Huhh, interesting question. I don't agree with whoever voted to close it, this is programming related and specific. (By the way, I was stumbling upon the exact same problem when designing my scripting language - I haven't yet finished it, but I found that this is easier to implement as a "semantic", run-time type of error.)

Comment: Hey @rici can you give an example where I can use any other grammar than CFG in Syntax analysis. From what I've studied if such additions are made to CFG, compiler might allow something that is not acceptable by the language.

Comment: @H2CO3 I also think that it would be beneficial if type checking is done at run time for scripting languages but what about imperative languages?
And could you clarify one thing, if language is statically typed will semantic errors would be produced under compile time errors? From lower classes I've been taught that there are basically two types of errors : compile time(syntax error) and runtime (logical). So where does semantic errors fit in?

Comment: @arg21 as far as I'm concerned, this is not strictly a syntax error - if I were to implement this for a statically typed language, like C, then I would **not** put the check into the parser (because the parser is incapable of checking this), rather into the code generator (the logic that walks the AST and turns it into assembly). So in my opinion, it lies between syntax and semantic errors - it's a syntax-related error that can anly be checked by performing semantic analysis. If we consider a primitive scripting language, where the AST is directly executed without compilation to bytecode

Comment: and without JIT, then it's the evaluator/executor function that walks the AST and finds the undeclared variable - in this case, it will be a runtime error. The difference lies between the AST-walk routine being in different parts of the program lifecycle (compilation time and runtime) should the language be a scripting or a compiled one.

Comment: @arg21: I didn't say that you should use something other than a CFG. I said that the CFG was not the totality of the syntactic analysis. For example, it's normal (and in C/C++ and many other languages necessary) to use a symbol table, without which it is impossible to correctly parse the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I see it it is a semantic error, because your language parses just fine even though your are using an identifier which you haven't previously bound--i.e. syntactic analysis only checks the program for well-formed-ness. Semantic analysis actually checks that your program has a valid meaning--e.g. bindings, scoping or typing. As @pst said you can do scope checking during parsing, but this is an implementation detail. AFAIK old compilers used to do this to save some time and space, but I think today such an approach is questionable if you don't have some hard performance/memory constraints.

Comment: I also agree that it is a semantic error but but is there any classification in a language (like in C,Java) between syntactic and semantic errors produced at compile time or are they just produced as a list of errors?

Comment: I think that's an internal implementation detail. GCC, for example, seems to just report a list of errors without taking into account if they are syntactic or semantic.

Comment: Thanks Alex that helps a lot. I used to think that semantic errors were only reported at runtime. My bad.

Comment: That's the case with most latently typed languages--also known as dynamic languages.

Comment: I think that when the C++ (or whatever) compiler creates the AST (abstract syntax tree) then it finds out that the variable does not exist, so it treats such things as syntax error. In C++ there are some situations where a type or a variable name are both valid things at a given point. There are others where only type is valid, so if you give a name of a variable or a mistyped name then you will have syntax error. I still consider not finding a symbol a semantic error, but I understand the rationale behind the "Syntax error" message in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

The program conforms to the language grammar, so it is syntactically correct. A language grammar doesn't contain any statements like 'the identifier must be declared', and indeed doesn't have any way of doing so. An attempt to build a two-level grammar along these lines failed spectacularly in the Algol-68 project, and it has not been attempted since to my knowledge.

The *meaning,* if any, of each  is a *semantic* issue. Frank deRemer called issues like this 'static semantics'.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is not strictly a syntax error - nor a semantic one. If I were to implement this for a statically typed, compiled language (like C or C++), then I would not put the check into the parser (because the parser is practically incapable of checking for this mistake), rather into the code generator (the part of the compiler that walks the abstract syntax tree and turns it into assembly code). So in my opinion, it lies between syntax and semantic errors: it's a syntax-related error that can only be checked by performing semantic analysis on the code.

If we consider a primitive scripting language however, where the AST is directly executed (without compilation to bytecode and without JIT), then it's the evaluator/executor function itself that walks the AST and finds the undeclared variable - in this case, it will be a runtime error. The difference lies between the "AST_walk()" routine being in different parts of the program lifecycle (compilation time and runtime), should the language be a scripting or a compiled one.

Comment: I don't think you can write a C++ compiler without taking account of declarations while building the AST. See my answer for a simple case in C, but there are much more complicated issues in C++.

Comment: @rici well, why couldn't you? I think you're confusing the abstract syntax tree with the abstract semantic graph.

Comment: How do you draw an AST for (a)-b, then? It fits into two completely different productions in the grammar.

Comment: @rici `SUBTRACT(EXPRESSION(TERM a), TERM b)`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: What if it's `CAST(TYPE a, UNARY_MINUS(TERM b))` ?

Comment: @rici Then it's just `CAST(TYPE a, UNARY_MINUS(term b))`. And that's what the AST will show. There'll be an error when *trying to evalue this.*

Comment: How will the AST show that if you don't know what `a` is when you parse it? And it's not an evaluation error: it's perfectly legal.

Comment: @rici the AST can contain an undefined type, why not? It's just that the compiler won't know what it means when trying to evaluate it.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. `(a)-b` can be either a SUBTRACT or a CAST (but not both), depending on whether `a` is a type or a variable. The parser cannot build the AST (which requires knowing whether to insert a CAST or a SUBTRACT) unless it knows what `a` is. So if it doesn't know, the parse must fail.

Comment: @rici Now I get what you meant. Yes, this is absolutely correct. I didn't consider this type of ambiguity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19022/discussion-between-rici-and-h2co3)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of languages -- and there are many -- which require identifiers to be declared, a program with undeclared identifiers is ill-formed and thus a missing declaration is clearly a syntax error.

The usual way to deal with this is to incorporate information about symbols in a symbol table, so that the parse can use this information.

Here are a few examples of how identifier type affects parsing:

## C / C++

A classic case:

```
(a)-b;
```

Depending on `a`, that's either a cast or a subtraction:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if TYPEDEF
typedef double a;
#else
double a = 3.0;
#endif

int main() {
  int b = 3;
  printf("%g\n", (a)-b);
  return 0;
}
```

Consequently, if `a` hadn't been declared at all, the compiler must reject the program as syntactically ill-formed (and that is precisely the word the standard uses.)

## XML

This one is simple:

```
<block>Hello, world</blob>
```

That's ill-formed XML, but it cannot be detected with a CFG. (Nonetheless, all XML parsers will correctly reject it as ill-formed.) In the case of HTML/SGML, where end-tags may be omitted under some well-defined circumstances, parsing is trickier but nonetheless deterministic; again, the precise declaration of a tag will determine the parse of a valid input, and it's easy to come up with inputs which parse differently depending on declaration.

## English

OK, not a programming language. I have lots of other programming language examples, but I thought this one might trigger some other intuitions.

Consider the two grammatically correct sentences:

```
The sheep is in the meadow.
The sheep are in the meadow.
```

Now, what about:

```
The cow is in the meadow.
(*) The cow are in the meadow.
```

The second sentence is intelligible, albeit ambiguous (is the noun or the verb wrong?) but it is certainly not grammatically correct. But in order to know that (and other similar examples), we have to know that `sheep` has an unmarked plural. Indeed, many animals have unmarked plurals, so I recognize all the following as grammatical:

```
The caribou are in the meadow.
The antelope are in the meadow.
The buffalo are in the meadow.
```

But definitely not:

```
(*) The mouse are in the meadow.
(*) The bird are in the meadow.
```

etc.

---

It seems that there is a common misconception that because the syntactic analyzer *uses* a context free grammar parser, that syntactic analysis is *restricted* to parsing a context free grammar. This is simply not true.

In the case of C (and family), the syntax analyzer uses a symbol table to help it parse. In the case of XML, it uses the tag stack, and in the case of generalize SGML (including HTML) it also uses tag declarations. Consequently, the syntax analyzer considered as a whole is more powerful than the CFG, which is just a part of the analysis.

The fact that a given program passes the syntax analysis does not mean that it is semantically correct. For example, the syntax analyser needs to know whether `a` is a type or not in order to correctly parse `(a)-b`, but it does not need to know whether the cast is in fact possible, in the case that it `a` is a type, or that `a` and `b` can meaningfully be subtracted, in the case that `a` is a variable. These verifications can happen during type analysis after the parse tree is built, but they are still compile-time errors.

Comment: So are you saying though the **syntax** is ill formed (syntactically incorrect not semantically), error will be caught during semantic analysis due to incapability of parser and it will be considered as syntax error?

Comment: @arg21: edited my answer to resopnd, rather than writing a huge long comment.

Comment: In your example of (a)-b what will happen if cast is not possible (if a is a type) ? Will it produce a compile time syntax error due to wrong semantics?
Also after studying few basic things about YACC, I get what you mean by parser not being restricted to CFG.

Comment: @arg21, C++ has a much wider repertoire of possible bad casts. You could experiment with c++ compilers and see what results you get. In C, one possible error is: `typedef int a[4];` which will generate `error: used type 'a' (aka 'int [4]') where arithmetic or pointer type is required` (at least, with clang, which usually has better error messages than gcc).

Comment: Semantic feedback to the parser is undoubtedly is required in many languages, but its presence doesn't convert semantic errors into syntax errors.

Comment: @EJP: Of course, well-meaning people may not share a dictionary. But I believe I use the word "syntax" with respect to C++ in a way similar to the way it is used in the C++ standard. For example, 6.8(3) "The disambiguation is purely syntactic; that is, the meaning of the names occurring in such a statement, beyond whether they are type-names or not, is not generally used in or changed by the disambiguation." makes it clear that whether an identifier names a type is syntactic. Similarly, 7.1.3(1) "Within the scope of its declaration, a typedef-name is syntactically equivalent to a keyword".

Comment: @nci That use of 'syntactic' specifically refers to type names, and it does so because type names appear in the grammar and so need to be disambiguated from identifiers for syntax analysis purposes. The statement you have quoted specifically excludes all other aspects of the 'meaning of the names', which includes whether it has been declared. If a name hasn't been declared it certainly can't be a type name. I don't know what the remark about the dictionary is supposed to mean.

Comment: @EJP: 3.3.1(1) "Every name is introduced in some portion of program text called a declarative region, which is the largest part of the program in which that name is valid, that is, in which that name may be used as an unqualified name to refer to the same entity. In general, each particular name is valid only within some possibly discontiguous portion of program text called its scope." That seems to me to be a purely syntactic description. Of course, we might disagree about the precise meaning of "syntactic", which is what I meant by my statement about well-meaning people and dictionaries.

Comment: @nci Syntax is defined by the grammar. You can change the subject all you want but you cannot get away from that fact. Typedefs are in the grammar, which is why the parser needs semantic feedback about them. Declaration of all variables is not in the grammar. Scope is not in the grammar. None of your quotations is to be found in the grammar. See my answer for further discussion.

Comment: @ejp. Grammar productions include `class-name: identifier` `enum-name: identifier` `template-name: identifier` and various others. It's quite clear that the C++ parser needs to figure out what type of identifier each identifier is during the parse. Take a look at the paragraph at Appendix A, and in particular A.1: "New context dependent keywords are introduced..."

Comment: @rici I agree, for the second time, but that doesn't make undeclared identifiers a syntax error. Where in the grammar does it say an identifier has to be declared?